# i want to print the json value passed from the controller in gsp page and use pagination in it using javascript?

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a controller where I  get all the race list and pass it to the GSP page as Json

```
     def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 4, 100)
    def raceAllJson=Race.findAll()
    [ raceJson:raceAllJson as JSON]

}
```

Now at the view page i want to display the json data(i.e raceJson) and paginate 3 data at a time.assume In the table it has NAME ,CITY and COST column.

In View i have tried the following code to parse JSON data but it is not working.

```
    <g:each var="raceList" in="${grails.converters.JSON.parse(raceJson)}">
        <td>${raceList.name}</td>
        <td>${raceList.address}</td>
        <td>${raceList.city}</td>
        <td>${raceList.cost}</td>
    </g:each>
```

My main target is to achieve the pagination view using javascript. once the value passes from the controller to the GSP page all the pagination must be done staying in the same clientside page.

Comment: Unless you are 100% sure that Race domain will not have too many objects, this is not a correct way to do this. Imagine how long it will take to render list of all Race objects if database contains 1 mln rows or more. When you need such functionality you do call from javascript with max and offset and render only part of it on server-side, then all or part of it on client side.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried in your gsp page. We can help you with your code but we will not write the codes for you :)

Comment: i am not able to even parse the JSON data and display only 3 data out of 10 data .i have tried the above mentioned code in my gsp page :(